# Multiple UITableViews as cells to one UICollectionview, more efficient Cell Reuse/Creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I've got multiple (n) tableviews I need to display horizontally.  I am using a UICollectionView where each collection view cell has a UITableView.    Each tableview takes up most of the screen, there are three tableviews (three cells) displayed at a time, with only a few pixels of the left and right tableviews showing when there is no scrolling going on.  All the table views are objects of the same class, and all use only one type of cell.

My problem is that every time I scroll to display the next tableview, all of the cells in the tableview have to be allocated and init'ed.  This is very expensive, and there is an obvious split second freeze if the new tableview has a full set of cells to display.  I had the idea of making a UITableView in my parent class (the one holding the UICollectionView) calling it a prototypeTableView and when I create the tableview cell I set that prototypeTableView as a property of that cell (the tableview).

Here is the code in my Parent class that holds the UICollectionView.  Where I set the prototypeTableView to the

```
    CollViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollViewReuse forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.theTableView.prototypeTableView = self.prototypeTableView;
```

Here's the code in my UITableView child class

```
MyTableViewCell *cell = [self.prototypeTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

My problem is that I get a nil cell back every time I dequeue a cell.  If there is a better way to do this please let me know.  I just wanted to test this and I can't completely call this a bad way to do it until I can get the table view to actually dequeue my cells!

Thanks!!

Comment: Where are you making your table view cells?

Comment: The second set of code is where I make the cells for my table views.

Comment: I mean where do you make their views? Are you making it in code or IB?

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah I am doing it in code.

Comment: You should get rid of the if (cell == nil) clause and register the class in viewDidLoad and see if that helps. You shouldn't ever get a nil cell if the class or nib is registered.

Comment: I changed it, and it is giving me a cell now, but I don't think it is reusing all the cells.  There was no change in the little freeze.

Comment: I'm also thinking about reusing cell across multiple tableViews. @KKendall Did you solved it in the end?

Comment: Did you tried using Paging? Instead of `UICollectionViewCell`